# Xamarin.forms android change software back button layout background color

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I change the software back button layout color at the bottom for xamarin.forms android app? It only shows white color. If we open google photos app we can see that the color is managed.
Please refer the images.

*1.  Xamarin.forms android app with white background for software back button*

[image]

*2. Google Photos app with dark color for software back button layout.*

[image]

How can we change the color? Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Api version is `Level 21` or above (`Android 5.0` and above).You could use `SetNavigationBarColor` method to set the background color.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        {
            Window.SetNavigationBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
        }

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
         
        ...
   }
```

Comment: will it change the color at bottom?

Comment: @Anand Yes,it will change the bottom navigation bar background color.

Comment: Ok bro...let me check

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can we make it dynamic?Is it possible?

Comment: We usually set it at the beginning, we don't set it dynamically.

Comment: Why I asked for the dynamic change is, when we change the theme, the bottom color stays as default set color.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the Theme of Android app.

tutorial here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. How exactly the theme going to change the color of specified item?

Comment: Because this is what Themes do. Default Theme is called Theme.AppCompat.Dark i think. Go to Resources folder, values, styles and you can see it all there.